# How can I plot the results of two dynesty runs on a single corner plot using dynesty.plotting.cornerplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two dynesty results, and I want to use dynesty's built-in plotting utilities to plot them on a single corner plot for comparison. How can I use dynesty.plotting.cornerplot to plot them on one corner plot?

I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this method:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ndim, ndim, figsize=(8, 8))
```

after this you can plot the first figure with dyplot:

```
fig1 = dynesty.plotting.cornerplot(results1, color='black', fig=fig)
```

and now:

```
dynesty.plotting.cornerplot(results1, color='red', fig=fig1)
```

I read the documentation and this method returns (fig, axes) and should it works, altought, if you use corner.py this method works 100%.